# Pass JSON data to next page in react native (hook)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, navigation, stack-navigator

I am learning reactnative.
I'm using the hook function.
There is no example of json data flip using hook function, so I leave a question.

I would like to pass group_id, one of the json data, to the next page.

```html
function HomeScreen({navigation, route}) {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [localItem, setLocalItem] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://103.51.240.53:8000/GetBestSeller")
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((localItem) => {
            setLocalItem(localItem)
            setLoading(false)
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
                 // ADD THIS THROW error
                throw error;
            });
    })
    
    <FlatList style={{backgroundColor:'block', opacity: 1}}
                    horizontal={true}
                    data={localItem}
                    renderItem={({item, index}) => 
                            <TouchableOpacity 
                            onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('Hot', itemID: item.group_id)}
                            style={{marginLeft: 10, alignItems: 'center', marginRight:10}}>
                     
                                <View style={{width: '100%', backgroundColor: '#02ad94', opacity: 0.5}}></View>
                                <Text style={{color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize:25, marginTop: 20}}>{item.name}</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                    }
                    keyExtractor={item => item.group_id}>
        </FlatList>
```

this is first page.

```js
 const Hot = ({route}) => {
    const { itemId }          = route.params;
    const { otherParam }      = route.params;
    return (
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.carouselText}>{itemID: item.group_id}</Text>
    </View>
    )
   }
```

this is second page.

I tried to pass it over using "navigation.navigate('Hot', itemID: item.group_id)" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `navigation.navigate('Hot', itemID: item.group_id)` is valid javascript syntax

instead try -

```
navigation.navigate('Hot', {itemID: item.group_id})
```

javascript objects are wrapped in `{}`

The react navigation docs has an example covering exactly this. - [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params)

Comment: I already added {}, but it didn't work:(.  hot page result : itemId: 0.